# Tools to find OpenVPN UDP packet corruption

Tags: networking, openvpn, udp

Are there Unix tools to troubleshoot UDP packet corruption? I'd like to avoid writing my own...

I think ping might report when a packet is corrupted, but it doesn't really seem to have options targeting corruption. I guess I'd like to find the BER and also—if possible—where in the path its occurring.

*(Background: I have three OpenVPN VPNs (all in UDP mode, using certificates) running between two Linux machines, over different ISPs. One of the VPNs occasionally spits out "Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed", which I believe means either that one of the VPN packets was corrupted in transit, or alternatively someone spewed random junk to the OpenVPN port. I'm guessing corruption, as it occurs mainly during a bulk transfer at night.)*

Comment: This is a problem above the UDP level, it is the VPN detecting the problem. If there are broken UDP packages, your application won't find out.

Comment: @vonbrand It happens on only one of the the three VPNs (with the same software and same config, except for IP/port). The UDP checksum should discard bad packets, bit its only a 16-bit checksum, so 1/65536 should make it through by chance.

Comment: Check cabling, etc. Is some cable passing near a fluorescent light (copious eletromagnetic interference, might be turned on only during the night)?

Comment: @vonbrand The lights here are off at night (this side is in a small office, so all of that is turned off at night) But I'm hoping to find some tool to just blast several mbps of UDP traffic across to confirm its actually packet corruption.

Comment: If you want to blast traffic around, use `nc` (aka `netcat`, part of [`nmap`](http://nmap.org)). You shold be able to see errors in the various counters associated to the interfaces, or by comparing what goes through to what was sent (just size for UDP). But again, if this is _only_ for one VPN, see if you can smoke out some difference which could explain the problem. Perhaps not-so-good network card, cable, switch port, network cable too near/parallel to electric cables, ...).

Comment: @vonbrand Using `nc` is more or less writing my own. I'd have to handle packet reordering, loss, duplication, etc. Might as well pull out the C compiler at that point. Seems like a nice utility to do this must already exist. There is other traffic flowing over the same path (at least, until it hits the ISP), and I've not seen a problem with it. But it doesn't have cryptographic HMACs on it to detect all issues. The various counters (both `netstat -s` and `ethtool -S` don't show an issue, at least on a quick glance)

Comment: No, just check if everything came through. No reordering required at all.

Comment: @vonbrand I'm pretty sure `nc -l -u` will just print packets as they're received, in whatever order they're received. And IP networks are allowed to re-order packets, to drop packets, etc. UDP doesn't abstract that away. So I'd have to deal with that when comparing what I sent vs. what I received.

Comment: Hmm... could `tshark` be useful here? Maybe `tshark -o 'udp.check_checksum: TRUE' ...`?